# How do I attach windbg kernel debugger to the local machine?

Tags: windows, windows-10, kernel, debugger, windbg

I have used `bcdedit.exe -debug on` and rebooted. However I still get the error:

```
---------------------------
WinDbg:10.0.19041.685 X86 
---------------------------
The system does not support local kernel debugging.

Local kernel debugging requires Administrative
privileges, and is not supported by WOW64.
Only a single local kernel debugging session can run at a time.
Local kernel debugging is disabled by default. You must run 'bcdedit -debug on' and reboot to enable it.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How can I use the local kernel debugger? I am on a Windows 10 x64 virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the 32-bit WinDbg:

> WinDbg:10.0.19041.685 **X86**

As you can see in the error message, kernel debugging *"is not supported by WOW64"* which is the 32-bit subsystem of Windows. That means you must use the 64-bit debugger in the x64 directory. It should print out `AMD64` instead of `x86`

Also make sure that you start windbg with admin rights